# F2py in Anaconda causes "Failed with exit status 1112"

Tags: python, module, fortran, f2py

I am trying to use F2py to run a Fortran code in Python, however I am not an expert in Python. I am using Python version 3.5.1 and Anaconda 4.0.0

Every single F2py tutorial says that one should execute for example:

```
f2py -c -m fib3 fib3.f
```

to compile a Fortran code fib3 in python, so after that I should be able to use the Fortran subroutine importing it at python. However I found that even the plain and simple f2py cannot be imported in Python from Anaconda

I tried

```
import numpy as np
np.f2py
```

and it says f2py is not a module so to execute the f2py tutorial command I had to do:

```
python C:\Users\pmachado3\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts\f2py.py -c -m fib3 fib3.f
```

And using the folder script address looks like it can load f2py in the *command line* but in the end of the execution of this code I was getting the error when there is no Visual Studio detected, so I installed Visual Studio compatible with my Python version. Now the code is "working" but in the end I get this error and no module is created:

```
Failed with exit status 1112
```

the error that was happenning before I installed the visual studio was:

```
Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

so It stopped after I installed visual studio. I am running everything from CMD.

First of all I would like to ask:
 Is there anyway easier to use f2py? I mean, another python version or installer? Because the tutorials shows it in a simple way just calling f2py but I am not even able to do that at this Anaconda version. And how could I fix this problem of the failed with exit status?

edit: When I say "working" I meant that it went one step further however not actually working. My fortran compiler is Gfortran. I actually used to use Force however Python was not detecting, so I downloaded Gfortran.

the output log is here:

```
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "fib1" sources
f2py options: []
f2py:> C:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\src.win-amd64-3.5\fib1module.c
creating C:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\src.win-amd64-3.5
Reading fortran codes...
    Reading file 'fib1.f' (format:fix,strict)
Post-processing...
    Block: fib1
            Block: fib
Post-processing (stage 2)...
Building modules...
    Building module "fib1"...
        Constructing wrapper function "fib"...
          a = fib(n)
    Wrote C/API module "fib1" to file "C:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\src.win-amd64-3.5\fib1module.c"
  adding 'C:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\src.win-amd64-3.5\fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'C:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\src.win-amd64-3.5' to include_dirs.
copying C:\Users\pmachado3\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.c -> C:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\src.win-amd64-3.5
copying C:\Users\pmachado3\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.h -> C:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\src.win-amd64-3.5
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_ext
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
customize IntelVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifl
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable DF
customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable efl
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\gfortran\bin\gfortran.exe
Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\gfortran\bin\gfortran.exe
customize Gnu95FCompiler
customize Gnu95FCompiler using build_ext
building 'fib1' extension
compiling C sources
creating C:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\Release
creating C:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\Release\Users
creating C:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\Release\Users\PMACHA~1
creating C:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\Release\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData
creating C:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\Release\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local
creating C:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\Release\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp
creating C:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\Release\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_
creating C:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\Release\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\src.win-amd64-3.5
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\src.win-amd64-3.5 -IC:\Users\pmachado3\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\pmachado3\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\pmachado3\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\include -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /TcC:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\src.win-amd64-3.5\fib1module.c /FoC:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\Release\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\src.win-amd64-3.5\fib1module.obj
Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\src.win-amd64-3.5 -IC:\Users\pmachado3\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\pmachado3\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\pmachado3\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\include -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /TcC:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\src.win-amd64-3.5\fortranobject.c /FoC:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\Release\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\src.win-amd64-3.5\fortranobject.obj
compiling Fortran sources
Fortran f77 compiler: C:\Program Files (x86)\gfortran\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -O0
Fortran f90 compiler: C:\Program Files (x86)\gfortran\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -fno-second-underscore -O0
Fortran fix compiler: C:\Program Files (x86)\gfortran\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -Wall -g -fno-second-underscore -O0
compile options: '-IC:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\src.win-amd64-3.5 -IC:\Users\pmachado3\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\pmachado3\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\pmachado3\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\include -c'
gfortran.exe:f77: fib1.f
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:"c:\program files (x86)\gfortran\lib" /LIBPATH:"c:\program files (x86)\gfortran\lib\gcc\i586-pc-mingw32\4.5.0" /LIBPATH:C:\Users\pmachado3\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\pmachado3\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Users\pmachado3\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\pmachado3\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_fib1 C:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\Release\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\src.win-amd64-3.5\fib1module.obj C:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\Release\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\src.win-amd64-3.5\fortranobject.obj C:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\Release\fib1.o /OUT:.\fib1.cp35-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:C:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\Release\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\src.win-amd64-3.5\fib1.cp35-win_amd64.lib
Found executable C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\link.exe
C:\Users\PMACHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo0tr52i_\Release\fib1.o : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
```

It looks different from what appears on CMD window, It here doesnt show the exit status 1112. I am not sure how to copi the CMD output I just used "I clip"

Comment: Why Visual Studio? What does it have to do with this? Show the error which requested you to install it.  What is your Fortran compiler? Try to do everything in the command line, don't open the Visual Studio IDE. Try to get the full error message from f2py.

Comment: I really don't get this: *"Now the code is "working" but in the end I get this error and no module is created:"* So what happens when it is "working"? Does it print something?

Comment: Regarding `np.f2py`: f2py is not loaded by default with NumPy, you must request it via `import numpy.f2py`

Comment: I edited with more info

Comment: Ok, so what is *"one step further"*? Which step? Which command did you execute? What was the full output? (please not just the last line with an error code, it is really not enough)

Comment: Just added the output, I didnt know how to copy the CMD to cpliboard, however the copied log looks different from the one shown in CMD. It looks like is detecting only the x86 Visual studio but I do have the x64 too.

Comment: Well, then who knows hen we can't see it all. It looks like it is complaining that your gfortran is 32-bit.